# How to automate amcharts using jasmine-protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, amcharts

I want to check this graph's data 
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd50i.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have a set of data loaded into the system and create a benchmark chart that is always correct. Then you take a screenshot of it and save it as a base image for comparision. Now if you load the same data again, if the chart logic is correct, you should see the exact same chart pop-up, take a screenshot of that and verify it with the base image.

This is because charts are not easy to automate. Some of them are inside iframes and elements inside charts are very difficult to capture. The above will not work if the data is always going to be dynamic. There are a lot of tools out there along with Protractor that facilitate this. If you are looking for a paid tool to reduce the hassle, try out Percy or Applitools.

Comment: Thanks Sankalan. I will try this solution.

Comment: This solution will not work for me as data is dynamic.